# Table formatting to the center

Tags: tables

I currently have the following table:[image: Table]

The code that I used to obtain it is the following:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\label{table:PAF_sigf_results}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{p{3.65cm} p{0.1cm} p{2.1cm} p{2.1cm} p{2.25cm} p{2.2cm}}
    \cline{3-6}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Sensitivity/ Specificity}}                 \\ \midrule
    \textbf{Method} & & \textbf{All} & \textbf{PQI Stage 1} & \textbf{Balanced PQI} & \textbf{Sensitive PQI} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Feature's mean, SD, and time course} & & 0.64/ 0.96 & 0.82/ 0.99 & 0.80/ 0.98 & 0.86/ 0.99 \\
    \textbf{Linear variability and time course} & & 0.31/ 0.78 & 0.70/ 0.92 & 0.52/0.94 & 0.68/ 0.92 \\
    \textbf{Non-linear variability (CTM)} & & 0.31/ 0.74 & 0.22/ 0.92 & 0.11/ 0.68 & 0.24/0.92 \\   
    \textbf{Total} & & 0.22/ 0.63 & 0.16/ 0.88 & 0.08/0.59 & 0.18/ 0.88 \\  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

I would like to know how I can center the columns highlighted in red on the image?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach here would be to use a column specification of the form `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<len>}` for those columns that you want centred while being set in `p`aragraph style (requires the [`array` package](//ctan.org/pkg/array)).

Here's an alternative using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for visual appeal and [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to make the columns of the `Sensitivity/Specificity` column group even (requires at least two compilations with every change of the elements using the same `<tag>` in `\eqmakebox[<tag>]`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry} % Just for this example
\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\small
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X *{4}{c} }
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Sensitivity/Specificity}} \\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
  \textbf{Method} & 
    \eqmakebox[thead]{\textbf{All}} & 
    \eqmakebox[thead]{\textbf{PQI Stage 1}} & 
    \eqmakebox[thead]{\textbf{Balanced PQI}} & 
    \eqmakebox[thead]{\textbf{Sensitive PQI}} \\
  \midrule
  Feature's mean, SD, and time course & 0.64/0.96 & 0.82/0.99 & 0.80/0.98 & 0.86/0.99 \\
  Linear variability and time course  & 0.31/0.78 & 0.70/0.92 & 0.52/0.94 & 0.68/0.92 \\
  Non-linear variability (CTM)        & 0.31/0.74 & 0.22/0.92 & 0.11/0.68 & 0.24/0.92 \\
  \textbf{Total}                      & 0.22/0.63 & 0.16/0.88 & 0.08/0.59 & 0.18/0.88 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) helps with making a table fit within a pre-specified width (`\linewidth` in the above case). It seems like you're specifically measuring column widths, which might be easier to estimate just using an `X`-column.

Comment: Hello Werner, many thanks for your reply! it indeed looks waaay better!

In order to use this in other tables, can you explain me the following commands (why they are there, etc):
- \linewidth at the \begin{tablular}
- {X *{4}{c} } 
- \eqmakebox[thead]

Many thanks for your time :)